# Клиентское приложение на PHP для БД из MS SQL

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu, sql-server

Всех приветствую! Нужна помощь в совете. Фактически, мне нужно создать отдельное **клиентское приложение на PHP** (где будет Окно входа: логин, пароль для входа), потом возможность заполнить БД (т.е изменить поля или удалить столбцы, полная возможность редактирования). Готовая база данных сделана в **MS SQL-Server** и главная задача: нужно как-то связать мою БД и сделать для нее удобное клиентское приложение на PHP.

Второстепенная задача: также есть веб-сервер, который развернут на **OC Ubuntu**. Есть ли возможность использовать написанное клиентское приложение на PHP на веб-сервере? (В плане PHP я почти 0, понимаю только некоторые базовые принципы и думаю, что есть возможность реализовать все это). Если у вас есть советы или какие-то полезные источники, буду благодарен.

Comment: смотрите в сторону phpmyadmin

Comment: @ArchDemon, а разве пхпмайадмин умеет в мсскуль?

Comment: @donRumata, нет, но автор ведь хочет реализовать аналогичное приложение. Будет где научиться